# Strange behaviour with for loop and range: found :Int required: scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[Nothing,String,?]

Tags: scala, compiler-errors

I say bizarre because the following code compiled for a long long time without complaint nor comment.

```
val depth = dbStuff.lookupSomeInt(blah, blah)
for (x: Int <- 0 to depth) {
 doStuffWith(x).orNot
}
```

and yet today it did not compile on ONE of my machines (while still compiling on another)

Here is the error:

```
[error] /Users/SomeOne/SomePath/SomeFile.scala:415: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Int
[error]  required: scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[Nothing,String,?]
[error]           for (x: Int <- 0 to depth) {
[error]                               ^
[error] one error found
```

Further up the food chain I did add a val:

```
  protected implicit val columnOrderByList = Seq.empty[Seq[String]]
```

This is the only change I'm aware of and the error occurred immediately after the addition.

The fix appears to be:

```
   for (x: Int <- Range(0, depth, 1)) {
     doStuffWith(x).orNot
   }
```

It refused all other attempts to get the "range" to work: e.g. `(0 to depth)` in brackets etc.

Hate to say it out load but errors like the scare the crap out of me. What would happen if this were say 500 compile errors instead of 1? Or what if a "fix" didn't become self-evident? Worse yet what if the root cause wasn't also self evident so a back-out wasn't even possible?

I'm sure some genius knows exactly what happened here and why but I have no real idea as to how to find out (as in what paths to follow) to figure this out on my lonesome...

Light would be welcome!

COMFIRMED: I remove the `protected implicit val columnOrderByList` and the original code compiles no problem -- I place it back in and I get the error as documented. By up the food chain I mean the `val` is in a class that is inherited by the class that has this compile error so the `val` would be in scope.

Answer (score 2):

This is just one of the problem that could happen when to many implicit conversions are in scope.

```
scala> 0 to 3
res0: scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive = Range(0, 1, 2, 3)
```

is equivalent to

```
scala> intWrapper(0) to 3
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive = Range(0, 1, 2, 3)
```

However,

```
scala> implicit val s: Seq[Seq[String]] = null
s: Seq[Seq[String]] = null

scala> 0 to 3
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(3)
 required: scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[Nothing,String,?]
       0 to 3
            ^
```

is equivalent to

```
scala> s(0) to 3
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(3)
 required: scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[Nothing,String,?]
       s(0) to 3
               ^

scala> s.apply(0) to 3
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(3)
 required: scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[Nothing,String,?]
       s.apply(0) to 3
                     ^
```

Your newly introduced implicit values has higher preference than the predefined one, therefore it is chosen. Normally, this shouldn't be a problem, but in this case `Seq` defines a method `to`, which can convert a collection to a collection of a different type. Its full [signature](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Seq@to[Col[_]]:Col[A]) is `def to[Col[_]](implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[Nothing, A, Col[A]]): Col[A]`, which explains the error message about the expected `CanBuildFrom`.

Lection: Minimize the scope of your implicits as far as possible.

Comment: Yeah, ditto. Highlight why one shouldn't have common types as implicits. The Seq is an Int => Seq, hence the conversion.

Comment: @sschaef I do generally avoid implicits as I'm aware of the potential nightmares they have been (ahem) implicitly implicated in. Did *not* expect that here. I understood that a `protected implicit val` *without* a supplied value was a contract that basically stated: "This value *will* be available in all subsequent classes that extend this class and that contract will be enforced by the compiler. Is there a more elegant way of enforcing *that* behaviour *without* this potential side effect?

Comment: @Techmag I don't understand your problem. But you can remove the implicit and then assign it to an implicit val when really needed.

Comment: @sschaef I'll raise another question to get what I really need answered as it'll take a bit of code to explain it clearly. I'm aware of the case of *this* problem and I have a work-around so current topic is at an end. The question I now have will be a new topic.